# Was there any relation between Sri Trailanga Swami and Sri Shyamacharan Lahiri?

Tags: trailanga-swami

Sri Trailanga Swami and Sri Shyamacharan Lahiri, both considered as incarnations of Lord Shiva by their devotess, were contemporary and both lived in Varanasi. Was there any relation between them? Kindly cite proper sources in answer.